# How to exclude products that have variations missing from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is a SQL query that I need to make, in which I have a parent Product. Under each product, multiple variations(again products) can be nested. Some of the variations may not be posted to Channel and I need to exlude all parents that have at least 1 child not included in ChannelReport.

```
   WHERE 1=1
     AND bvc_Product.ClientID=100
     AND bvc_Product.Status=1
     AND VariationProduct.ProductID is not null
     AND VariationProduct.ChildProductID IN (SELECT productid FROM 
    ChannelReport wpal WHERE wpal.productid = 
    VariationProduct.ChildProductID)
```

Sample data would be:

T-Shirt1 - Product ID
S, M, L - 3 different variations. Each technically a productID as well.

T-Shirt2 - Product ID
S, M, L - 3 different variations.

T-Shirt1-M is not on ChannelReport as a productID. All T-Shirt2 variations are in ChannelReport. In this case, the result should be only:

T-Shirt2

Comment: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2976/95107

Comment: Original post edited with sample data.

Comment: There is nothing like sample data, and that is nothing like sample data. Please post something that makes sense. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Even without seeing your table, I can tell you this.  Any time you have a requirement like:

> all *x* that have at least 1 *y*

You need to use EXISTS().   Psuedocode for your requirement:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT child FROM Table WHERE ChannelId NOT IN (SELECT Channelid FROM ChannelTable))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NOT EXISTS twice

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM VariationProduct VP
    WHERE VP.ProductID = bvc_Product.ProductID
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM ChannelReport WHERE ProductID = VP.ChildProductID )
)
```